Inconsistent folder naming across browsers in Streamlit
I have a very simple streamlit app that uses Path from pathlib to display the folder name of the uploaded files. Works as expected on Firefox but not in Chrome-based browsers (nothing is shown): I understand that might be due to some security differences between the browser but does anyone know a solution or a workaround?
Reproducible code:
Python : 3.11
Streamlit: 1.39.0
pathlib: 1.0.1
import streamlit as st
from pathlib import Path

uploaded_files = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Choose files", type="txt", accept_multiple_files=True)
if uploaded_files:
    for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
        folder_name = Path(uploaded_file.name).parent.name
        st.write(f"Original file name: {folder_name}")

I tried opening a private session to exclude some influence from third party add-ons but the problem persists.
